# How to make Next Js 13 web app into a PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, next.js13

I am trying to make my next js 13 app site into a pwa,

I have generated the manifest.json file and installed next-pwa, configured next.config. The confusing part is where im supposed to put the _document.js file since now next js does not have that folder anymore.

next config here

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({

    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  });

  module.exports = withPWA({
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Next JS App router, you can make use of `Metadata API` to define your PWA meta tags in the root layout file.

Example of setting the meta tags

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  applicationName: 'My App',
}
```

You can add the meta tags to `app/layout.tsx`

Find the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) and all meta tags [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadata-fields)

Comment: Let me give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

You can create the _document.js file within your pages folder...